# Must Windows system locale be system wide?

Tags: winapi, locale, codepages

hello, all. Must Windows system locale(or say, system codepage, 1252, 936, 950 etc) be system wide? You know, in Windows 2000 ~ Windows 7, changing the system codepage in Control Panel requires a reboot to take effect.

I'd like to know whether I can have per-logon-session locale setting or even per-process locale setting? That will ease debugging program running with different locale.

BTW: I found GetCPInfo() Win32 API but no corresponding SetCPInfo, sigh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the system locale is the whole system, but users and processes/threads can change their own locale.
The thread local can be set using `SetThreadLocale()`.
Anything else is not in the remit of your program to change.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still curious about why Microsoft made such a decision not allowing changing system locale on a process basis or logon-session basis. Could you do more explanation?

Comment: Because it's a user setting, not for your application to change. If you want to change it, it's thread specific as mentioned above.